# FindElements By.Xpath is not working in linux

Tags: c#, linux, selenium, xpath

I have 5 elements and I want to get 1the first element and click it. When I try my code on windows I can get all elements and it is working and I can click that element and download excel1. But when I push my code to Linux it does not work in my `link` returns null. How can I click it.

My code:

```cs
var link = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom']")); //i can not get my elements on linux
link[1].Click();
```

and my elements

```html
<div>
  <div class="mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;"><a class="text-secondary" style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #0c0c0c; cursor: pointer;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Table-1</span> click download for excel0</a></div>
  <div class="mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;"><a class="text-secondary" style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #0c0c0c; cursor: pointer;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Table-2</span> click download for excel1</a></div>
  <div class="mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;"><a class="text-secondary" style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #0c0c0c; cursor: pointer;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Table-3</span> click download for excel2</a></div>
  <div class="mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;"><a class="text-secondary" style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #0c0c0c; cursor: pointer;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Table-4</span> click download for excel3</a></div>
  <div class="mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;"><a class="text-secondary" style="font-size: 1.2rem; color: #0c0c0c; cursor: pointer;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Table-5</span> click download for excel4</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The class attribute value might be dynamic. You can anchor class attribute. Please provide enough wait to load the page completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a delay before accessing these elements.
To check this issue just put some delay of several seconds before

```cs
var link = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='mt-3 mb-3 w-100 border-bottom']")); //i can not get my elements on linux
```

line. In case it fixed the problem use `WebDriverWait` expected conditions explicit waits instead the hardcoded pause to make your code better.

Comment: i have 7  ```System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);```  before that line but still i get null. i will try to ```WebDriverWait``` when i fix my problem. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure `WebDriverWait` will help in case hardcoded sleeps did not work. ....
Maybe the elements are out of the visible view port on Linux while they were visible on Windows?

Comment: No they are visible cause i can get my excel when i start my cron manuel but when i set the time to my crontab - e it return null in that line.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. We need to actually debug this to see what actually happens on your side...

Comment: i find the reason sir and i want to tell you my solution. when my code start on windows chrome open automatically 1920x1080 but my chrone job when start it is open some width and height(idk) and as you say they are not visible and i think when the screen open small width Selenium is not see my elements and return null. now i set the **chromeOptions.AddArguments("window-size=1200,1100");** it is working now. thanks your answer sir.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! BTW we normally use `(1920, 1080)` screen size

Comment: ok i will set 1920x1080